# MySQL: how to select top buyers and sum the total orders?

Tags: mysql

i have the following query

```
SELECT 
    SUM(order_total), 
    CONCAT_WS(" ", `first_name`, `last_name`) AS `Customer Name`, 
    COUNT(order_id) 
FROM orders 
JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
```

and the summation is not true, i need sum the total of each customer

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `GROUP BY`. When you don't add it (and use a aggregate function like `SUM` or `COUNT` in your columns-part), MySQL will group all rows in a single result. It can't magically know you want to know the result for each customer, so you have to explicitly tell it.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(order_total), 
    CONCAT_WS(" ", first_name, last_name) AS Customer Name, 
    COUNT(order_id) 
FROM orders 
JOIN customers ON orders.customer_id = customers.customer_id
GROUP BY customers.customer_id
```

Comment: you are right, i tried the group by but there is some data still not displayed! something wrong